# H.264 encoding using FFMPEG - some videos not working

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, h.264

Can anybody provide their 'most robust' FFMPEG command line for encoding to H.264?  We've tried a few but some videos do not want to play ball.  I'm sorry, I don't have the exact errors on hand - was just hoping to get somebody else's command line, before I spend time trying to work out exactly which type of videos aren't encoding, or why.

Thanks heaps.

Comment: You should provide more specific details such as your OS and what you're targeting the output for. Showing the ffmpeg command and the complete console output is always useful; we can actually see the exact errors and give you details as to why it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ffmpeg command line I use for encoding videos to baseline so that they play on all the various iOS hardware:

```
ffmpeg -y -i $INPUT -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset:v slow -profile:v baseline -crf 20 $OUTPUT
```

The INPUT is typically a .mov file encoded with the lossless Animation codec. The OUTPUT is like "xyz.m4v"